# CircleCI 2.0 SSH debug: Failed to enable SSH, No SSH key is found

Tags: circleci

Config:

- CircleCI 2.0
- Bitbucket private repo

After I click on "Rebuild with SSH", the "Enable SSH" section outputs

> Failed to enable SSH
>   No SSH key is found. Please make sure you've
>   added at least one SSH key in your VCS account.

What does this mean? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use your personal private public `id_rsa` `id_rsa.pub` key-pair (which you may already generated to SSH access to other machines)

just add your public key `~./ssh/id_rsa.pub` to Bitbucket -> Settings -> SSH keys -> add SSH key

then go to CircleCI and rebuild the project.

---

There may be confusion because CircleCi uses other SSH key called checkout SSH key-pair for:

- checking out the main project
- checking out any Bitbucket-hosted submodules
- checking out any Bitbucket-hosted private dependencies
- automatic git merging/tagging/etc.

Private checkout SSH key is saved on circleCi servers and public key is automatically uploaded to Bitbucket.

Comment: I added SSH key to my bitbucket account (not repo), but I still get "Failed to enable SSH" in CircleCI

Comment: @CarsonIp It worked before, but now I think the problem on their side (CircleCI and Bitbucket APIs): https://discuss.circleci.com/t/debug-with-ssh-has-stopped-working-in-bitbucket/27949

Comment: thanks for the link! I asked the question in 2017 and I still haven't had the luck to use the SSH feature in 2019. I'll be waiting for updates in the CircleCI discussion thread.

Comment: From CircleCI support: "Thank you for your patience while we have investigated this issue. A change has been made to the Bitbucket API to tighten security that was not compatible with how we previously handled SSH keys for BitBucket users. We are currently in communications with the team over at BitBucket to discuss potential resolutions for this issue. We are unable to provide an ETA at this time but will do our best to provide updated information when possible."

Comment: The issue has been fixed on 8 Apr 2019. This answer is right. But if you have a team, you must add the SSH key under the personal account instead of the team.

Comment: @CarsonIp you should post that comment as an answer, I've been trying to fix this for ages and this is the only place I can find on the internet that mentions it should be on your personal user not on your team.

Comment: @Shardj right. I was stuck for a long time too. Adding a TLDR to this accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

**If you're using Github:**

- go to your keys setting: https://github.com/settings/keys
- generate a key pair if you don't have one
- copy and paste the key in the CircleCI UI and save.

You should immediately be able to log in with SSH into the CircleCI now (run `rerun job with SSH`).

**If you're using Bitbucket:**

- Add your public key to your bitbucket account: choose Bitbucket settings from your avatar in the lower left
- Click ssh keys and add your public key
- You don't need to do anything in CircleCI, simply re-run the job using SSH

sources:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html